# Xcode5.1 unit test code coverage missing for ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing

For my iOS project, I have setup unit testing and code coverage.
While tests are succeeding, and code coverage statistic generally seem to be correct, I get 0% coverage on my ViewControllers, even though I have verified these tests have run.

My question is how can I make sure these unit tests are included in code coverage.

Here's my setup:

- Xcode 5.1, using the XCTest unit testing framework and OCMock (via Cocoapods).
- [XcodeCoverage](https://github.com/jonreid/XcodeCoverage) for measuring code coverage. I used John Reid's [guide](http://qualitycoding.org/xcode51-code-coverage/) to get this to work.
- I have run unit tests both using CMD+U on the main target (all tested classes get coverage, except ViewControllers), and by clicking the small diamond in the margin of the test class (only some helper classes get some coverage)
- I set a breakpoint on the ViewController unit tests to verify these are actually running.

To verify the error was not caused by XcodeCoverage, I used [coverstory](https://code.google.com/p/coverstory/) on the test results, and the coverage was the same. I have also verified that the .gcda and .gcno files are actually created during testing.

Example of a unit test:

```c
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import <OCMock/OCMock.h>
#import "MyViewController.h"

@interface MyTest : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation MyTest

- (void)testViewDidLoad
{
    MyViewController *controller = [self getViewController];

    [controller viewDidLoad];

    XCTAssertTrue([controller.screenName isEqualToString:@"MyScreenName"]);
    XCTAssertTrue([controller.navigationItem.title isEqualToString:@"My VC"]);
    XCTAssertNotNil(controller.menuButton);
 }
- (MyViewController *)getViewController
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    MyViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
    return controller;
}
@end
```

I think I should note that, in spite of XcodeCoverage's guide, I measure code coverage on the Test Target instead of the main target (which means basically that gcda and gcno files are used that occur in

```
{BuildFolder}/Build/Intermediates/App.build/CodeCoverage-iphonesimulator/TestTarget.build/Objects-normal/i386/
```

instead of .../MainTarget.build/... because I noticed that the latter location only gets coverage of code that is run on starting the app in the simulator, while the other gives coverage of (most of) the unit tests. I don't know why this is different in my setup from what is advised.

Thanks in advance.